# store.subscribe() not working in helper service function on state change

Tags: reactjs, service, redux

Basically, I get a token in my login api response which is used in network requests as header. I store this token in my redux store. I use axios for all my api calls. I have created an axios instance like following:

axios.js

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3003',
    // timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: ~token~,
        environment: 'production'
    }
});
```

So that I can call my apis in thunks like :

```
const resp = await axiosInstance.get(`/log/dashboardchartdatafromdate=${dateData.dateRange.from}&todate=${dateData.dateRange.to}`);
```

I have tried subscribing to the redux store like the following inside `axios.js`:

```
import configureStore from '../store';

 configureStore().subscribe(() => {
    token = configureStore().getState().loginReducer.token; //access token here
    console.log(token);
 });
```

My store looks like this:

store.js

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const composeEnhancers = window.REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE || compose;
  return createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
}
```

My problem is the code block is not working on state changes. It only works once on the application start.

I am not sure if I can subscribe store inside a helper service function like I have tried. Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Hmm why would you need to subscribe to your store in the first place? Do you just want to see if the token is in your reducer?

Comment: I need to get the token from my store to use it in my http request header.

Comment: Oh I see. Well I don't think you have to subscribe to your store to do that, although that is an innovative idea. You can really just pull the token from your reducer while doing your thunk request. I can show you how to do that if you're interested.

Comment: Sure. I can check if that would help me.

Comment: Great! Just wrote you an answer, let me know if that's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action creator will just have to look something like this. You can make use of the optional getState() function that is available as an argument inside thunk actions. This is a better alternative than having to subscribe to your store.

**axiosInstance.js:**

```
export default const axiosInstance = (token) => {
   return axios.create({
       baseURL: 'http://localhost:3003',
       // timeout: 10000,
       headers: {
          Authorization: token,
          environment: 'production'
       }
   });
}
```

**Your action file:**

```
import axiosInstance from "./axiosInstance"


const getDashboardData = (dateData) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const token = getState().loginReducer.token

        const resp = axiosInstance(token).get(`/log/dashboardchartdatafromdate=${dateData.dateRange.from}&todate=${dateData.dateRange.to}`);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the `getState` inside my thunk and it had worked fine. But I wanted to define the axiosInstance in a separate js file, like a service, so that I need not re-write it in all my api-call thunks. The method you suggested would want me to rewrite the axiosInstance in all my thunks. Am I right?

Comment: Hmm that's a fair assessment. We can always try to create a function that would return your axiosInstance and pass in the token to it. Let me edit my answer to help us accomplish more reusable code.

Comment: Cool! Is that working any better for you? The idea is to just keep the axios template in another file. Import the function and pass in the token whenever necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. I was just making it too complicated by subscribing the store.

Comment: You're very welcome @AnittaPaul! You had a pretty cool idea there, I never would have considered using store.subscribe() to update something else. Hopefully redux will allow us to do more with that method in the future :)